# Lambda F#: getting minimum value from list regardless if input is string or int

Tags: lambda, f#, higher-order-functions

I created a folder helper function to help with my project

```
let rec fold f v xs =
    match xs with 
    | [] -> v
    | (x::xs) -> f (x) (fold f v xs )
```

and now I need a function that helps me get the minimum value from a list, but I don't want to use iteration or recursion. I've come up with the following:

```
let min l = fold (fun acc -> min acc) System.Int32.MaxValue l
```

tested the function on a list of integers `min [4;2;3;34;]` and got the expected desired output :

```
val min : l:int list -> int
val it : int = 2
```

Now, how would I go about making this function applicable on strings too? For example `min ["do"; "je"; "ca"; "ja"]` is `"ca"`
I'm trying to avoid using built-in List functions for the purpose of forcing myself to use helper functions and lambdas. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your `min` function work on both integers and numbers, you need two things:

- Make it `inline` so that the F# compiler can use static member constraints (which will mean that it can work on values of any type that support comparison)
- Get rid of the `Int32.MaxValue` constant, because that restricts the type to integers only.

The first is just a matter of adding the `inline` keyword. For the second, you could either pass in maximal string (but no such thing really exists). A better option is to take the first element as your initial value and run `fold` on the rest. Since `min` cannot work on empty lists, you can throw exceptions when the list is empty:

```
let inline min l = 
  match l with 
  | x::xs -> fold min x xs
  | [] -> invalidArg "l" "Cannot get minimum of empty list!"
```

Now you can use the function on both numbers and strings:

```
min [4;2;3;34;]    
min ["do"; "je"; "ca"; "ja"]
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to have a one line solution instead of using pattern matching?

Comment: @Later_72 You could do this as a one-liner if you used `List.reduce` rather than your `fold` (which is equivalent to `List.fold`) - `List.reduce min l` would do!